# hg log - How to get the last 5 log entries?

Tags: mercurial

I have a Mercurial project that has hundreds of commits.

When I want to look at the most recent entries I type

```
hg log
```

and then wait for everything to print out and then scroll back to the top.

How do I print out just the 5 most-recent entries?

Answer (score 113):

Use the limit parameter: `hg log --limit 5`

Comment: When I use this with a revset (ie. `-r user("foo")` the order is not "last five", but "first five".

Answer (score 24):

In completion of the Michael Markert response you can use the shortversion

```
hg log -l 10
```

In addition if you want you can define via the option `-b` that you want only last commit from the current branch.

You can also do

```
hg log -l 10 -b [your branch]
```

for check 10 last commit from the branch you want

Of course you can go further with `-d` like this :

```
hg log -l 1 -d "feb 2015 to apr 2015"
```

This will give you last 10 commits within this date range (3 char for each months)

And goes on..

Full example and option are available in this link :
[Here](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/log)