# First vs. last changesets using hg log's -l and -r

Tags: mercurial

When I use `hg log -l 5` I get the last 5 changesets.  When I use `hg log -l 5 -u goldberg`, I get my last 5 changesets.  But when I use `hg log -r 'user(goldberg)' -l 5`, I get my *first* 5 changesets.  If I want to do any complex search, I'm stuck with -r, which always gives me the *first* changesets when I limit with -l.

Is there a way to get -r to provide a last-to-first set so that I can use it with -l/--limit to get the latest relevant changes?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835511/hg-log-how-to-get-the-last-5-log-entries) is pertinent but doesn't get at the difference between these cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need `-l` when using revsets:

```
hg log -r 'limit(reverse(user(goldberg)), 5)'
```

(This works on 2.0 at least, I don't know about older versions.)

Comment: Works on 1.9.3 as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Revsets were introduced in v1.7 so anything later than that should be fine.