# How to limit to N newest entries with Hg Log when specifying a Revset?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, hg-log, mercurial-revsets

This question is not a duplicate of [hg log - How to get the last 5 log entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835511/hg-log-how-to-get-the-last-5-log-entries) - it is easy to apply a limit. The problem is that the log output, *when limited*, does not appear to always be ordered descending by log date - the behavior changes with the addition of a revset.

For example, the simple log work "as expected" and it is displays the *newest* five log entries.

```
hg log -l5
```

However, when using a revset the result is the *oldest* nodes first (as observed without `-l`); hence the following shows the *oldest* five entries which is not desired.

```
hg log -r "user('Me')" -l5
```

How can can `hg log`, with a revset, be instructed to order by the log date *descending* ("as expected") so that the limit has a predictable<sup>1</sup> and meaningful effect?

---

```
$ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.6.1)
```

<sup>1</sup> I don't consider throwing random `reverse` calls in a rev*set* predictable, but if that is the "best" way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options you have.

First, you can use `reverse()` in conjunction with your existing revset, e.g.:

```
hg log -r 'reverse(user("me"))' -l 5
```

As a shorthand, you can also use `-f` or `--follow`, which – when used in conjunction with `-r` – will wrap the revision in `reverse(...)`. Example:

```
hg log -f -r 'user("me")' -l 5
```

Or you can encode the limit in the changeset, e.g.:

```
hg log -r 'last(user("me"), 5)'
```

Note that revset aliases can be useful to avoid having to type out revsets over and over. So, you can put something like this in your `.hgrc`:

```
[revsetalias]
lastby($1) = last(user($1), 5)
```

And then do:

```
hg log -r 'lastby("me")`
```

Comment: Pure shoddy Hg log behavior. And here I just previously created a confluence page praising rev*sets*. So much for being the "James Bond".

Comment: FWIW, the `reverse` method is unreliable as there is no guarantee of consecutive date ordering in the subset (I've just run into a case where it is is not); it would have to be done with `sort(..,'-date')`.

Answer (score 0):

Important addendum answer: do *not* use `reverse` blindly for this task. While it will work in many cases, the better/reliable generic solution is to use `sort`, as in:

```
hg log -r 'sort(user("me"), "-date")' -l 5
```

This is because `reverse` *does not guarantee the source set order is well-ordered* - as such it may still result in final output that does *not* meet the requested criteria of 'newest'.

The use of `sort` above guarantees the behavior as it sorts by the date, descending, and then selects the top 5 per hg log's limit option.

(Otherwise, see Reimer's answer.)